# Flex breaking AS3 focus functionality in SWC

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I've got a flashbuilder air/flex app that used SWC's for all of it's graphic/window content that I've inherited and have run into a problem that i do not know how to solve.

The SWC has multiple text inputs which the user can tab through. However, when that SWC is loaded in flash builder pressing tab only causes the focused text field to lose focus and nothing appears to gain the focus next.

I've manually captured the tab keypress via a keyDown event listener inseide the SWC's AS3, however even setting stage.focus or setSelection() has no effect when running inside the flashbuilder app.

Is there something i can do to tell air/flex/flashbuilder to allow the focus events of the SWC?

Comment: That it is a SWC is irrelevant really, code is code. If any DisplayObject cannot get focus it's usually because something prevents it like other stuff on top of it.

Comment: All of the text fields can receive focus through clicking on them it's just tabbing between them that stops working when publishing as a swc for flashbuilder vs as a swf.

Comment: You are implying that your swc somehow break functionality, it is just precompiled code, it does not and cannot break anything. If something does not work properly it is in your code. You'll just be voted down until you understand that SWC does not break code or functionality.

Comment: Blaming the code is not a valid in this instance as input field tabbing is native/automatic in to flash. All i can say is that it works when run in debug mode or published as a SWF, yet not as an embedded SWC.

I've closed this question as i ended up having to write my own input tab/focus manager from the ground up as a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've closed this question as i ended up having to write my own input tab/focus manager from the ground up as a workaround.